# How to read only first child value in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I'm new to Firebase I wanted to know is there a way to only get the value of first child and insert it into my spinner in android. Ex:

[image: this]

Just like the image shown I wanted to retrieve only the name "slot x" instead of getting all the values of it. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing, you can [order and limit the number of child nodes retrieved](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) with something like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference myRef = rootRef.child("path to your parent node");
Query query = myRef.orderByKey().limiToFirst(1);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = childSnapshot.getKey(); // "slot 1"
            String status = childSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class); // "occupied"
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```